# Do you need to include update records in before flows?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am working on updating a bunch of workflows to flows. With the new migrate to flow tool it's putting in an update record element even if it's a before action.

[image]

In other flows I've done I neglected to put in an update and just went with assignments and it works fine.

[image]

My question is is the update element needed? If I include the update would it be doing a dml update after the save and thus increasing cpu time?

Right now I am working on non triggered objects and concatenating fields into the name so it's probably going to be pretty quick either way but eventually I'll move into my larger objects like Opportunity and I want to make sure I'm as efficient as possible.

Comment: by definition, workflow rules ran after update hence why the Migration Tool might have added the Update records element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's called out in [Record Triggers for Flows That Make Before-Save Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_trigger_record.htm&type=5)

> When the flow changes the values in the $Record global variable,
> Salesforce automatically applies those new values to the record. **So
> there’s no need to add an Update Records element to save the new
> values to the database.**

I would provide feedback on the [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.migrate_to_flow_tool_considerations_workflow.htm&type=5) page for the conversion tool about this behavior. It's expected that workflows that only update the same record would be converted to before-save flows.

> If a workflow rule contains only field updates, the tool converts it
> into a fast field update (before-save) flow.

But, the fact that it is using an update element shouldn't cause issues as it'll still act as a before-save update to the record. There's the following information when you edit the update element that mentions this:

[image]